# Print() Python Error (Brand new to Python) "Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)"

Tags: python

I am brand new to Python. Followed a video on how to download. Downloaded and am using PyCharm CE. I just tried to run the most basic bit of code...

**num=49**
print(num)

I keep getting this error in response when I run this...

**Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)**

I have tried a bunch of little things, but I so new to Python trouble shooting has been difficult for me. Is this a memory space issue? Or some other basic thing that I didn't do when setting up my Pycharm envrionemnt? I can't image this is too tricky to solve, hopefully someone has some simple answers!

Thanks!

I tried to follow some solution videos online but they didn't really lead me anywhere productive. I cannot get any bit of code to run without this error.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are you using an M1 Mac by any chance? If so, does this help: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4405185776018-Problems-running-Python-programs-on-PyCharm-on-new-Mac-Book-Air-m1-apple-silicon- ?